# How can I keep an application alive with alternative to infinite loop or console read key? (if possible)

Tags: c#

I need ti run a Windows application that contains timer and multiple thread. This application do not require any interaction with user. I need to run it and keep it alive until I decide to kill it. For real it will be a Windows Service. For testing I run and infinite loop but this infinite loop seems not the best way to work.

Here is my launcher

```
        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            new NotificationService().OnStart();
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(600000);
            };
#else
           ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new NotificationService()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
        }
```

I think my Thread.Sleep really freeze all my process, even my time I create in NotificationService. This next code is part of my NotificationService:

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Logger.Info("Start NotificationSystem");
            Timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            Timer.Interval = 12000; // 12 seconds
            Timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
            Timer.Start();
        }

        public void OnStart()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }
```

I process all my business in OnTimer method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to run your service project directly, then it's fairly common to allocate a console for it. You can also use this to allow users to install the service, by passing command-line parameters.

You can block this Console until it receives Ctrl-C:

```
private static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool AttachConsole(int pid);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        RunService();
    }
    else
    {
        if (!NativeMethods.AttachConsole(-1))
        {
            NativeMethods.AllocConsole();
        }

        RunConsole();

        NativeMethods.FreeConsole();
    }
}

private static void RunService()
{
    // ...
    ServiceBase.Run(...)
    // ...
}

private static void RunConsole()
{
    var closeEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) => closeEvent.Set();

    new NotificationService().OnStart();

    closeEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

---

Alternatively, it's not uncommon to have a separate Console project which references your Service project, which is just used for testing.

---

Although these solutions are neater than a timer with a long sleep, they will have the same effect of blocking the main thread (which is somewhat unavoidable). I think the problem with your notification service is a separate issue.

Comment: Yes but... because my process will at the end be a Windows Service it is not a console app but a Windows App. I don't have reference to Console.

Comment: @BastienVandamme 1) Service projects can use `Console`, if you use `AllocConsole` / `FreeConsole` / `AttachConsole` 2) It's common to use a separate console application project which references your service project, for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Quartz.NET and Topshelf for this job.
Here's a [link](https://www.olivercoding.com/2018-06-29-quartz/) and I hope it helps you.